# What is a concise function that formats a (String) decimal into a currency format in Apex?

Tags: apex, math

goal:
write the most concise function that formats a (String) decimal into a currency format in Apex. Feel free to trainwreck the code for points, I've kept mine exploded for readability purposes.

Comment: Is this an actual problem you are facing or just a way to entertain the troops? Typically we don't allow *"getting to know you"* -type questions posted strictly for social and entertainment value. Perhaps your question is better suited to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com?

Comment: it was a problem I was facing, and I solved it with the code I supplied. I had a hunch I was recreating the wheel so I used the code golf format to elicit responses. I have seen other examples of code golf in the past on SE. Of course a new exchange would be created for that purpose, cant seem to keep up with you guys ;)

Comment: I didn't have a problem with this question specifically, as long as the context and motivation was sound. Enjoy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**UPDATE**: More robust solution from @jkraybill elsewhere.

Here's one that's shorter AND is locale safe:

```
public static String currency(String i) {
    String s = ( Decimal.valueOf(i==null||i.trim()==''?'0':i).setScale(2) + 0.001 ).format();
    return s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
}
```

Check out Number Format in the [list of supported locales](http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_supported_locales.htm). There's "1.000,00" and "1 000.00" amongst others. Not everyone uses "1,000.00" so we shouldn't assume that in a formatter. Decimal's format() method [is locale aware](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm).

Comment: I could do it all in one line if Apex's substring() acccepted negatives in the second argument for chopping off the right. You'd have blah.format().substring(0,-1)

Comment: Your method doesn't handle empty strings, I made a slight edit to fix that.  Basically changing your `(i==null?'0':i)` to `(i==null||i.trim()==''?'0':i)`

Comment: Out of interest, why is `0.001` added after the rounding and before the call to format?

Comment: Adding 0.001 means we have two zeroes after the decimal place without altering those two decimal places. The format then strips off the 1

Comment: In case anyone needs to handle fractional currency and/or negative values, be aware that this method doesn't handle either quite correctly -- I posted an edited version that does.

Comment: New String methods can make the string part more readable: (i==null||i.trim()==''?'0':i) to (String.isBlank(i)?'0':i)

Answer (score 13):

@RickMeasham's method is a good one, but I ran into a couple rounding issues with negative values and fractional values. Here's my edited version of the method that passes the tests I needed it to (not rendering -0.001 as "-0.00", not rendering -1.10 as "-1.09").

```
public static String formatCurrency(Decimal i) {
    if (i == null || Math.abs(i) < 0.005) return '$0.00';
    String s = (i.setScale(2) + (i >= 0 ? 0.001 : -0.001)).format();
    return s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
}
```

(EDIT: changed "<= 0.005" to "< 0.005" per @RickMeasham's advice below.)

(EDIT 2: actually realized, when I finished tests, that this updated method still had a few shortcomings related to rounding. I updated to delegate to Math.roundToLong per code below [which uses round half even, not half up as I stated in my comments erroneously]. It now passes all my unit tests, which you can see here: http://codepad.org/ycttSXjq)

```
private String formatCurrency(Decimal i) {
    if (i == null) return '0.00';
    i = Decimal.valueOf(Math.roundToLong(i * 100)) / 100;
    String s = (i.setScale(2) + (i >= 0 ? 0.001 : -0.001)).format();
    return s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: This is better than mine, though @jkraybill, you should change `<= 0.005` to just `< 0.005` as 0.005 should round *up* rather than down.

Comment: Good catch, in fact depending on your rules for "round half up" (specifically if 0.005 -> 0.01 but -0.005 -> 0) it would need to be more specific than that. Your mod brings it into compliance with Java's "round half up" logic but I'm not sure what the financial industry uses.

Comment: Financials industry does half-up around here. 

I was going to say the *main* reason to round half-up is that .setScale does. But it doesn't. It does HALF_EVEN rounding (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Decimal_setScale.htm). 

So we should switch the setScale to the two-argument version and specify HALF_UP (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_decimal_rounding_mode.htm)

Comment: New rounding mode link (atlas docs, alas): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_decimal_rounding_mode

Answer (score 3):

Ok - first, I'm not actually recommending the following approach. It's more of an intellectual exercise - an exploration of a different path to a solution.

First, create the following Apex page:

```
< apex:page Controller="currencyfuncontroller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
    < apex:outputField id="formattedamount" value="{!DummyOpportunity.Amount}" />
< /apex:page>
```

The controller is as follows:

```
public class currencyfuncontroller
{
   public Opportunity getDummyOpportunity()
   {
       String currencystring = 
         Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('currencystring');
       Decimal currencyvalue = 0;
       try
       {
           currencyvalue = Decimal.ValueOf(currencystring);
       } catch(Exception ex) {}
       Opportunity op = new Opportunity(amount = currencyvalue);
       return op;
   }
}
```

Here's some simple code to use it:

```
ApexPages.PageReference pr = Page.currencyfun;
pr.getParameters().put('currencystring','1.56');
String contents = pr.GetContent().toString();
system.debug(contents);
```

You still need to parse out the actually currency value - but that's easy enough to do use a regular expression or some substring work, so I left it out here. I also cheated by using an exception handler instead of the (better) validation shown in other answers - just to keep things simple.

What does this approach accomplish?

- The formatting now includes the correct currency symbol for the user's locale (and currency formatting should it differ from standard decimal formatting).
- You could extend this to include a parameter for the currency to use and use that info to set the currency type for the opportunity. On multi-currency organizations this should provide automatic currency conversion to the current locale with the formatting (standard SFDC formatting on multi-currency organizations).

Again - If I really needed this I'd probably actually write the code to lookup currency symbols, examine the current and corporate currency, and do the necessary conversions and formatting directly. But that's quite a bit of code (especially on orgs using advanced currency management).

Ultimately my point is - the original question was asking for formatting a decimal string into currency format, and the job isn't really done until you have the correct currency symbol and multi-currency handling in place :-)

Answer (score 3):

Of course, it all depends on your use case.  Most of the time, you don't need to do this in Apex since the value is destined either for display on a VisualForce page or storage via a Currency field.  That said, you'd be able to do this in pure Apex if it weren't for the type restriction on the String.format(...) method.  Requiring a List<String> for the arguments prevents you from doing it in pure Apex, at least easily.

If the point of the Apex code is to provide a value for display in a VisualForce page, then Apex really need not do anything but provide the raw decimal value:

```
<apex:outputText value="Total: {0, number, currency}">
  <apex:param value="{!aDecimalValue}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

No need for a dummy SObject with a currency field, although that certainly works.

Comment: my particular requirement needed dynamic json, using hardcorded vf tags mixed with json wasnt a direction I wanted to take.

Answer (score 2):

The original Solution posted above is slightly incorrect as it doesn't handle negative numbers..

Use this method instead..

```
public static String currency(String i)
{
    // - Error this doesn't handle negative number converts -15 to -14.999  instead of -15.001 before round
    //String s = ( Decimal.valueOf(i==null||i.trim()==''?'0':i).setScale(2) + 0.001 ).format();
    //return s.substring(0,s.length()-1);

    if (( i == null) || ( i == ''))
    {
        return '0';
    }
    else
    {
        string s;
        if ( Decimal.valueOf(i) >= 0 )
        {
            s =  ( Decimal.valueOf(i).setScale(2) + 0.001 ).format();
        }
        else
        {
            s = ( Decimal.valueOf(i).setScale(2) - 0.001 ).format();
        }
    return s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

670 characters

```
public static String currency(String input){
    if(input == null){return '0.00';}
    if(input.indexOf('.') == -1){input = input+'.00';}
    if(input.length() == 5){return input+'0';}
    String newValue = input.substring(input.indexOf('.'));
    newValue = String.valueOf(Decimal.valueOf(newValue).setScale(2));
    newValue = newValue.substring(newValue.indexOf('.'));
    input = input.substring(0,input.indexOf('.'));
    Integer sz = input.length();
    Integer n=0;
    for(Integer i = sz - 1;i > -1;i--){
        if(n!= 0 && math.mod(n,3) == 0)
            newValue = input.substring(i,i+1)+','+newValue;
        else
            newValue = input.substring(i,i+1)+newValue;
        n++; 
    }
    return newValue;
}
//unit test, doesnt count
static testmethod void test_currency(){
    system.assertEquals('2,105.00',currency('2105.0'));
    system.assertEquals('320.00',currency('320.0'));
    system.assertEquals('1,500.26',currency('1500.256'));
    system.assertEquals('0.00',currency('0.0'));
    system.assertEquals('0.00',currency(null));
    system.assertEquals('10,000,123.56',currency('10000123.558'));
}
```

Comment: Should the last assert read
system.assertEquals('1,500.26',currency('1500.26'));

Comment: the value being passed in should be .256, its testing the decimal rounding part of the method.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick, with the assumption that your locale for currency formatting is correct.
Edited to handle null being passed, and zero values after the decimal.

```
public static String currency(String input) {
    if ( input == null ) {
        return '0.00';
    }

    Decimal d1 = Decimal.valueOf(input).setScale(2);
    String str = d1.format();
    if( !str.contains('.' ) ) {
        str = str + '.00';
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: failed the first test:
15:44:29.595 (595496000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 2,105.00, Actual: 2,105

Comment: Believe that edit should do it.

Comment: Not for 0.1. It returns 0.1 rather than 0.10

Answer (score 0):

Rarely should you ever need to format variables like that in Apex.  Since that's typically a view issue, I tend to rely on apex:outputField for that scenario in Visualforce. Kibitzer has the right idea.

Comment: Depends on your definition of rare: this post wouldn't exist and neither would ideas like this https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000KlHoAAK if there wasn't a need sometimes for this functionality e.g. building message strings in Apex code. I suggest that salesforce's product managers don't spend enough time using their product to understand how many gaps there are in what they provide. And they do a great job of ignoring the ideas forum they created.

Answer (score 0):

One of options is to store the value in the currency field in some object, like

```
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(
    Name='Test', StageName='Closed',CloseDate=Date.today(),Amount = 12345.60
);
insert o;
o = [SELECT FORMAT(Amount) formattedAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :o.Id];
System.debug(o.get('formattedAmount'));
```

Then in debug log we can see the formatted value

```
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|€12,345.60
```