# System.TypeException: Invalid decimal Error in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, currency

I have a currency field in object. I am assigning value to it in apex

For US users: the currency format is 241,500.00 so when i apply decimalof on this i am getting 241500000.00.

But for Eur users: the currency format is 241.500.00000, so when i apply decimalof on this i am getting **Invalid decimal: 241.500.00000**

```
String s = 241.500.00000 or 241,500.00 ; 
mar.flowvalue__c = decimal.valueOf(s);
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14823/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-currency-field-from-a-formatted-string

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately while the [Decimal class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) has a `format` method:

> **format()**
> Returns the String value of this Decimal using the locale of
>   the context user.

there is no equivalent `parse` method that respects the user's locale.

The approach that side-steps the problem is to use things like `<apex:inputField/>` that does respect the locale in the string conversion and stores a Decimal value after the parsing rather than a String. Otherwise you will have to write your own locale aware parse method.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal.valueOf isn't locale-aware. Consider binding to a Decimal directly on the page, as this automatically handles conversion to/from the user's locale for you:

```
<apex:input type="number" value="{!mar.flowvalue__c}" />
```

Or

```
<apex:inputText value="{!mar.flowvalue__c}" />
```

Or

```
<apex:inputField value="{!mar.flowvalue__c}" />
```

Any of the above methods will be locale aware and do the appropriate conversion for you.

If you want to assign a known value in your code, use a literal decimal value:

```
mar.flowvalue__c = 241500.00;
```

Even if you don't want to bind directly to the field, you can still use a Decimal value:

```
public Decimal flowValue { get; set; }
```

---

```
<apex:input type="number" value="{!flowValue}" />
```

Or

```
<apex:inputText value="{!flowValue}" />
```

Basically, the point is, bind to a Decimal value, and you'll automatically get the benefits of locale-aware Decimal parsing.