# How to convert a number into a formatted string?

Tags: apex, formatting, string, decimal

Note: there is an [extensive discussion on converting a string into a decimal](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-is-a-concise-function-that-formats-a-string-decimal-into-a-currency-forma).  This question asks how to convert a number into a formatted string.

Given a decimal variable, how can I convert that into a formatted string, such as a currency string, i.e. 2000 would become "$2,000.00"?  I would have thought this would be an easy task, given the formatting options available in visualforce, e.g. `<apex:outputtext value="{0,number,$#,###.##}">`, but there doesn't seem to be analagous functionality for apex.  Is there a simple method for achieve this?

I first looked at the `decimal.format()` method, but this doesn't take any parameters.  Was hoping for something like this

```
Decimal input = 2000;
String output = input.format('$#,###.##');
```

I also looked at the `String.format(formatString, inputArray)` but you can only use string data types for the input array.  Was hoping for something like this

```
Decimal input = 2000;
String output = String.format('$#,###.##',new Object[] { input });
```

Comment: This is discussed at length in this existing SFSE thread:

[What is a concise function that formats a (String) decimal into a currency format in Apex?][1]


  [1]: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-is-a-concise-function-that-formats-a-string-decimal-into-a-currency-forma

Comment: @greenstork, I saw that, but it's focused primarily on the reverse case, given a currency string how do I convert it to a decimal.

Comment: @Bachovski am I missing something or is this not a duplicate?  The other question is talking about String -> Decimal, this is the opposite, Decimal -> String.  What am I missing?

Comment: @highfive am I missing something or is this not a duplicate? The other question is talking about String -> Decimal, this is the opposite, Decimal -> String. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tepsi am I missing something or is this not a duplicate? The other question is talking about String -> Decimal, this is the opposite, Decimal -> String. What am I missing?

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 am I missing something or is this not a duplicate? The other question is talking about String -> Decimal, this is the opposite, Decimal -> String. What am I missing?

Comment: @greenstork am I missing something or is this not a duplicate? The other question is talking about String -> Decimal, this is the opposite, Decimal -> String. What am I missing?

Comment: sorry guys, it's too late at night, apparently I can't read

Comment: [Decimal].format() formats the Decimal value into the locale of the current user. Is there a way of formatting a Decimal to an arbitrary locale (or format) in Apex?

e.g. 
Decimal decimalValue = 10000.00;
String stringValue = decimalValue.format('###,###,##0.00');

Comment: @cyorkston post a new question and reference this one, i'm the only who would see this comment, to the best of my knowledge you'd need to write you're own function, but a new question would get a lot more people to look at and confirm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format method automatically does the commas and periods or visa versa (depending on whether your profile is in the US or elsewhere)

Assuming the $ sign applies to all cases in your org you can simply use

```
Decimal input = 2000;
String output = '$' + String.valueOf(input.format());
```

Note the String.valueOf(). This is required because the input variable is defined as a Decimal.

Edit:
I noticed a bug with the Decimal.format() method where it will not show any numbers past the decimal point if there are only zeros there, ex. $100.00. To solve this I came up with this method.

```
private String getCents(Decimal x){
    String y = String.valueOf(x);
    String z = '.';
    if(y.contains(',')) z = ',';
    y = y.substring(0, y.indexOf(z));
    if(x - Decimal.valueOf(y) == 0)
        return String.valueOf(x.format()) + z + '00';
    else return String.valueOf(x.format());
}
```

Then to update the example above, it would be:

```
Decimal input = 2000;
String output = '$' + getCents(input);
```

Comment: Nice approach, it doesn't take care of the currency part, but at least we get a number in the correct locale ...

Comment: Your String.valueOf() is unnecessary.  The Decimal.format() method returns a string by default.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm

Answer (score 3):

This should work, if its until 2 decimals:

```
Decimal dec;
String amount;
if (!string.valueof(dec.format()).right(3).contains('.')){
    amount = '$' + string.valueof(dec.format()) + '.00';
}else if (string.valueof(dec.format()).right(2).contains('.')){
    amount = '$' + string.valueof(dec.format()) + '0';
}else {
    amount = '$' + string.valueof(dec.format());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more version , this one determines the "decimal separator" automatically and adds trailing zeros based on the scale provided.

```
public static String formatNumberFields(String unformattedValue, Integer scale) {
    String formattedValue = Decimal.valueof(unformattedValue).setScale(scale).format();
    Integer decimalPlaces;
    String decimalSep = 0.23.format().substring(1, 2);

    if(formattedValue.contains(decimalSep)) {
        decimalPlaces = formattedValue.split('\\' + decimalSep)[1].length();
    } else {
        formattedValue += decimalSep;
        decimalPlaces = 0;
    }

    //Add trailing zeros
    while(decimalPlaces < scale) {
        formattedValue += '0';
        decimalPlaces ++;
    }

    return formattedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i created a class for Utility functions like this.

Here is the code in the Utility class

```
public static String formatMoney(String s) {
    s = '$' + s;
    if (!s.contains('.')) {
        s = s + '.00';
    } else {
      Integer dPos = s.indexOf('.');
      if (s.length() - dPos < 3) { s = s + '0'; }   
    }
    return s; 
}
```

Then in my apex class I create a string that will show on my VF Page and call the function

In this particular case the money is coming from a query

```
String poTotal {get;set;}

poTotal = Utilities.formatMoney(poInfo[0].PO_Amount__c.format());
```

I can call the Utility function from any apex class and it will format my Decimal value into the string with $1,123.00

But it can be done with anything

```
String myMoney {get;set;}

public void myFunction() {
  Decimal amt = 1234.1;
  myMoney = Utilities.formatMoney(amt.format());
```