# How can I add cents (including .00) with setScale?

Tags: apex, decimal

If in an Apex class I set some decimal values like so:

```
public List<String> args = new String[] { '0', 'number', '#,###,###.##' };

public String getPrice() {
    Decimal amount = (lead.Price__c).setScale(2);
    return String.format(amount.format(), args);
}
```

It will return prices either like so: `1,234` or `1,234.5`. How can I change my method to return cents so that it'll return `1,234.00` or `1,234.50`? I tried the format in `args`, and I tried setting the scale to 2, and neither work.

Any help?

Comment: Nah, it doesn't really have the same implications as currency formatting. It might have been asked on SFSE, but not there.

Comment: @vamsi, you marked it as duplicate of the wrong one. He is not asking to convert a string to a currency.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38520/how-to-convert-a-number-into-a-formatted-string that's the one